# Difference between gobuster and dirbuster in performance

Tags: brute-force, websites, web

The only difference I am aware, is of CLI vs GUI. But I am curious to know as to what is the difference in their performance and what are the additional features in one tool compared to another?

Comment: The way to find out is to try it against a server that you can enumerate and see the result for yourself. Different people prefer different tools.

Comment: You can track performance indirectly using `time` command.